# Is there a way to make a PowerShell GUI tab transparent?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I want to make the tab background of my PowerShell GUI transparent, so you can see the full picture imported as the window background.

[Tool transparency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVOSF.png)

It neither worked with the BackColor property from the tabpage, nor with the BackColor property from the tabcontrol.

`$tabPage1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromName("Transparent")`

If I set the Backgroundimage in the tab as in the window, they don't align properly.

[Tool background alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwoL0.png)

Is there a way, to display the whole image porperly as a backgroundimage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is possible using a OwnerDrawn transparent TabControl, but if it is, this would take a lot of code.

Why not add two buttons on top of the form, acting like the tabstrip of a TabControl and add two Panel objects for the icons, where each button sets one of the panels to be visible and the other not visible.

Panels are easy to make transparent after all.

Here's a demo of what I mean:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# enable rich visual styles in PowerShell console mode:
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.ClientSize = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(256,200)
$form.TopMost = $true
$form.Text = "Your Choice"
$form.BackgroundImage = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile('D:\BackGround.png')
$form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'

$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button1.Text = 'vCenter Tools'
$button1.Location = [System.Drawing.Point]::new(0, 0)
$button1.Width = 100
$button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true  # buttons are not transparent
$button1.Add_Click({
    $panel2.Visible = $false
    $panel1.Visible = $true
})
$form.Controls.Add($button1)

$button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button2.Text = 'SystemChecks'
$button2.Location = [System.Drawing.Point]::new($button1.Width, 0)
$button2.Width = 100
$button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true  # buttons are not transparent
$button2.Add_Click({
    $panel1.Visible = $false
    $panel2.Visible = $true
})

$form.Controls.Add($button2)

$panel1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$panel1.Location = [System.Drawing.Point]::new(0, $button1.Height + 4)
$panel1.Size = [System.Drawing.Size]::new($form.Width, $form.Height - ($button1.Height + 4))
$panel1.Anchor = 'Top','Bottom','Left','Right'
$panel1.BackColor = 'Transparent'

# add your icon buttons to the panel
# for demo just an image button
$thingy1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$thingy1.Location = [System.Drawing.Point]::new(90, 80)
$thingy1.BackColor = 'White'
$thingy1.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile('D:\SomeIcon.png')
$thingy1.AutoSize = $true

$panel1.Controls.Add($thingy1)
$form.Controls.Add($panel1)

$panel2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$panel2.Location = $panel1.Location
$panel2.Size = $panel1.Size
$panel2.Anchor = 'Top','Bottom','Left','Right'
$panel2.Visible = $false
$panel2.BackColor = 'Transparent'
# add your icon buttons to the panel
# for demo just an image button
$thingy2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$thingy2.Location = [System.Drawing.Point]::new(90, 80)
$thingy2.BackColor = 'White'
$thingy2.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile('D:\StackOverflow.png')
$thingy2.AutoSize = $true

$panel2.Controls.Add($thingy2)
$form.Controls.Add($panel2)

[void]$form.ShowDialog()
$form.Dispose()
```

This is what it will look like:

[image]